# How to embed flash into article in joomla3?

Tags: joomla3.0

I have installed joomla3 in my local computer. I have created different categories. I want to add article with flash but not able find any control for inserting flash file in editor. When I write embed tag in HTML source and try to insert it removes it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some R&D I have found answer myself. Go to Etensions-> Plug-in manager -> Editor - TinyMCE.
In Basic Option set Functionality to "Extended". And then you will find control for embeding flash in editor in article.